# Here offroad navigation using LocationDataSourceAutomotive

Tags: android, here-api

I want to guide the drivers using our application on areas that are not mapped by Here. Problem is that the PositioningManager gives "map matched" positions that are sometimes far from the position the truck actually is.

So I used LocationDataSourceAutomotive to provide my own positions (raw positions given by the device) and everything is fine (PositionIndicator is moving on the map, getLastKnownPosition() is good, etc.) except that the navigation is not working.

I start navigation using

```
NavigationManager.getInstance().startNavigation(route);
```

But I don't get any instruction in the NewInstructionEventListener. And I'm not "re-routed" when I'm not following the computed route.

Does anyone have an idea why and how I could work around this issue or to achieve the same goal (offroad navigation) using other means ?

Answer (score 1):

LocationDataSourceAutomotive is not mean to be used in this manner.

Generally off road navigation is not supported by the engine. If your device is positioned at places without the road network the navigation engine continues to match against the known road network. It will resume navigation if the user travels back on the route or drives onto a road on the known road network.

Also, the positioning manager will callback with different types of positions. Please do instanceof MapMatchedPosition to differentiate whether the onPositionUpdated callbacks from Navigation manager are matched or raw.

Comment: Can you clarify how you do that ? I can't find the class MapMatchedPosition in the sdk. I know there is a boolean "mapMatched" in the PositioningManager callback but I don't know how to get the original position. What I want to do is prevent map matching for positions that are too far away of a known route (which is the default behaviour, but I'd like to be able to lower the distance threshold). I thought I could acheive this using LocationDataSourceAutomotive get***StandardDeviation methods.

Comment: Ok I think you meant MatchedGeoPosition which does contain the raw position. That's useful but how can I set the PositionIndicator at this position ? Is it not too late at this point ?